# Using a buildroot distro as a docker *host*

Tags: docker, host, buildroot, docker-engine

I have an ARM based board that can only run a specific buildroot based distro provided by the manufacturer. I would like to try to run Docker on this board.

Any time I combine buildroot and docker in a Google search, I wind up getting pages that explain how to use buildroot to create a container, not how to alter buildroot to use it as the host.

Can anyone point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keyword you're missing is "engine".
It's the [Docker Engine](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-engine) that allows the host OS to support Docker containers.

[image]

There's a submitted 3-part [patch](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2016-May/162235.html) to add Docker Engine support to Buildroot.

```
[Buildroot] [PATCH v6 0/3] Add docker engine support

This series adds runc, docker-containerd, and docker-engine support.

Patch 1 adds runC, the new minimal CLI for running linux containers.
Patch 2 adds docker-containerd, the daemon and API for runC.
Patch 3 adds docker-engine, the cli and api for the Docker application
engine.
```